# How to called many function in one function using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have many functions. I am using an asp.net control.
I want to call all of functions in one (main) function. This is a return type function.
This must use Javascript.

```
function a(){
    if(b==c){
    return true
}else{
    return false;
}

function b(){
    if(b==c){
        return true;
}else{ 
    return false;
}

function c(){}//return type
```

Function a, b, and c called function in main function.

```
 function main()
    {
   //??
    }
```

This function is not a work.

Comment: Call the `main` function. `<script>main();</script>`

Answer (score 2):

You either want:

```
function main()
{
  return a() && b() && c() && d(); // all must be true to return true
}
```

or

```
function main()
{
  return a() || b() || c() || d(); // at least 1 must be true to return true
}
```